# Meaning of TortoiseHg graph colors

Tags: mercurial, colors, branch, tortoisehg

What is the logic of those lines and changeset points colors? Does TortoiseHg automatically assign a color to each named branch? In the same named branch, the lines don't have the same color of the changeset points (like purple points with blue lines), why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found out why the dots and lines have different colors:

- **Dots** follow the color of **named branches**
- **Lines** follow the color of **anonymous branches**

When an anonymous branch is created, the dots remain with the same color but the color of the line changes.

Answer (score 0):

> Does TortoiseHg automatically assign a color to each named branch?

Yes, and to anonymous - also

> In the same named branch, the lines don't have the same color of the changeset points (like purple points with blue lines), why?

Because you can have enabled also "Author coloring", which which description of changeset have different colors for different authors

You can hardcode brach colors at any time

[image: Setting dialogue]

Comment: the "Author coloring" is off and even if it was enabled, all of the commits were made by the same user. I created a repository with 9 branches trying to understand what happens with these colors: [test repository](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/85/tortoisehgbranches.png/). The image is croped, the author column is not showing, but it's the same for all of them.

Comment: Dots (changesets) have same (permanent for branch) color, as commit-message. Color of lines can differ from color of changeset... all colors are random choice, AFAIK

Comment: Ok, I made some more tests, it looks like there's no logic at all, working with a lot of branches in tortoisehg is a complete mess of random colors. That's not very usefull.

Comment: You can hardcode branch color on global or per-repo (more usable, IMHO) basis: Settings - WorkBench - Branch colors

Comment: I tried that already, but it seems that this feature is broken, there's an open issue: https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issue/1111/branch-colors-not-working